# Calculated column with custom ID

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a list form which contains 3 fields: Company (choice field), NewID (lookup number field) and MyID (number field with min/max values 0000-9999).

On NewID field lookup formula is set:

`=IF([External-ID]>999,CONCATENATE("18",[External-ID]),IF([External-ID]>99,CONCATENATE("180",[External-ID]),IF([External-ID]>9,CONCATENATE("1800",
[External-ID]),CONCATENATE("18000",[External-ID]))))`

Depends of what I will choose on "Company" I need to have different "prefix"+MyID=NewID.

Eg.: When I will choose in "Company" Comp1 (which has prefix "18") I should received NewID as 180001 etc.

How I can set start value for field MyID as "0000" and hide if from Form to be auto-increment (but not based on original ShP ID field).

Best,
ZiBi

Comment: the TEXT function can format numbers

Comment: ok, but what about auto-increment?